# Python, load and list a .csv in a numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy

I am loading a .csv file with this code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial

points = np.array([((int(R), int(G), int(B)),float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
              for R, G, B, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('XYZcolorlist_D65.csv'))])
    # load R,G,B,X,Y,Z coordinates of 'points' in a np.array  

print points
```

And that works fine.

However, if I add this further line, where I am trying to compute a Delaunay triangulation with `scipy`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html

```
tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points[1, 2, 3])
# do the triangulation
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gary\Documents\EPSON STUDIES\delaunay.py", line 15, in <module>
    tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points[1, 2, 3])
IndexError: too many indices
```

Obviously the syntax `scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points[1, 2, 3])` isn't correct.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

If it's easier to handle, I can also use this line to import (np arrays should be of same type of data?)

```
points = np.array([(float(R), float(G), float(B), float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
              for R, G, B, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('XYZcolorlist_D65.csv'))])
    # load R,G,B,X,Y,Z coordinates of 'points' in a np.array
```

Then I would need to skip the first 3 values in each row...

Comment: `map(float, row) for row in reader` is simpler syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The error is with the slicing of `numpy` array. To get the coordinates of the points, either version of you code is fine.

First version of your code, where the first column of `points` is a tuple of RGB values:

```
tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points[:, 1:])
```

Second version, where the RGB values are flattened, taking up 3 columns, you need to skip three columns:

```
tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points[:, 3:])
```

In fact, you can use `np.loadtxt` for reading in the data (yielding the second version):

```
points = np.loadtxt('XYZcolorlist_D65.csv')
```

Comment: Mind posting first few row of ``points``? What is the dimension of the points that needs to be triangulated?

Comment: `print points[1:4]` returns the first 3 rows: `[[(255, 95, 127) 40.2074945517 26.5282949405 22.7094284437]
 [(255, 127, 127) 43.6647438365 32.3482625492 23.6181801523]
 [(255, 159, 127) 47.1225628354 39.1780944388 22.9366615044]]`, I want to get the values inside, not the entire rows

Comment: *get the values inside* - can you give an example? For the first point, you want ``[40.2, 26.5, 22.7]``?

Comment: Do you actually want all the points in ``points``, but skipping the first column which represents the color?

Comment: EDIT: I added another way of loading the csv

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but maybe it's something like this...you can replace file_txt with your csv reader.

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
>>> file_txt = [[255, 95, 127, 40.2, 26.5, 22.7], [255, 127, 127, 43.6, 32.3, 23.6], [255, 159, 127, 47.1, 39.1, 22.9], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
>>> a = [list(map(float, row[3:])) for row in file_txt]
>>> a
[[40.2, 26.5, 22.7], [43.6, 32.3, 23.6], [47.1, 39.1, 22.9], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
>>> Delaunay(a)
<scipy.spatial.qhull.Delaunay object at 0x0383FA30>
```